# POD start only 1 container

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

Hi I don't know whether this is an issue that I am having since I don't have a lot of experience in Kubernetes.

I am trying a deployment in Kubernetes but the logic behind the container it is that it start initialising it self instantly and calling a backend endpoint to register a user.

From the screenshot below I don't know whether this is an misconfiguration about my deployment but I think that the POD starts multiple containers and this breaks my deployment since the flow goes like this:

1. Container starts
2. Calls backend endpoint and register user
3. Kubernetes starts another container
4. Calls backend endpoint and fails to register user because its already been registered
5. POD fails to deploy

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cfoh.png)

As you can see in the screenshot the container count is `5`

Adding as well the deployment yaml file

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vulos-hyperledger-scanner
  namespace: vuloss-scanner
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vulos-hyperledger-scanner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vulos-hyperledger-scanner
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: vulos-hyperledger-scanner
          image: registry.digitalocean.com/notarised/vulos-hyperledger-scanner:1.6.5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: do-registry

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vulos-hyperledger-scanner
  namespace: vuloss-scanner
spec:
  selector:
    app: vulos-hyperledger-scanner
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-production"
  name: vulos-hyperledger-scanner
  namespace: vuloss-scanner
spec:
  rules:
    - host: explorer.vulos.io
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: vulos-hyperledger-scanner
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
  #This section is only required if TLS is to be enabled for the Ingress
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - explorer.vulos.io
      secretName: explorer-tls
```

I don't know whether this is an issue in my deployment and whether this statement of above makes sense in Kubernetes and whether I can make the `POD` to start only 1 container rather than multiple

Thank you

Comment: The YAML you show only starts one Pod and one Container; it doesn't have any of the logic you describe to call an endpoint or dynamically launch another container.  I'm also not totally clear what's in the image file you've attached.  Can you edit the question to include the required code and clarify the problem you're having?  For example, if your code is failing because a user has already been registered, is there code that performs that registration and an error it produces?

Comment: There is only 1 container, the screenshot clearly indicated your container has failed to run. What you are seeing is kubelet attempts to restart the failed container, **not** running multiple containers. Check your application log to see what went wrong.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you guys for the support. As I stated above I am not that proeficient with Kubernetes that's why I couldn't debug where the issue was it seems that is in the code side.

Regarding the code side I am using this open source project and the issue its here: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/fa20bd950f9c4d90ff8260f7b2ed55c6309793b3/app/platform/fabric/gateway/FabricGateway.ts#L240